# How do I open/edit/convert Markdown documents in Office OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, text-formatting, markdown

We have a bunch of text files in Markdown format and we want to share them with the relevant members of the team using Office OneDrive. As far as text file formats, OneDrive only seems to understand Word documents or files with `.txt` extension.

Is there a way of opening/editing/converting text files with Markdown formatting in OneDrive?

Comment: When you say "share" can you clarify whether you want to share read-only or share with edit capabilities. Your colleagues also have OneDrive installed? What about Office 2013 on the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Currently neither OneDrive, nor Google Drive support the markdown format natively. While there is the [StackEdit](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackedit/iiooodelglhkcpgbajoejffhijaclcdg?hl=en) extension for Google Drive, I am not aware of a similar one for OneDrive. There are some services, though, which allow documents importing from and saving to OneDrive. One example is [Dillinger](http://dillinger.io/).

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing you can save text files with the `.md` file extension within [OneDrive Personal](https://onedrive.live.com/) and the Web App will detect the markdown formatting and render the file as HTML in the preview. However, this worked better in the past and it feels like Microsoft is probably [phasing simple text files out](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_yammer-mso_o365brs-mso_o365b/yammer-notes-for-topic-groups-being-converted-to/a8934d54-fba5-4433-b9eb-10040fbdacb6) in favor of [Word Online documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Converting-Yammer-notes-into-Word-Online-documents-1aaec7ab-109b-4477-92be-6b558fb731ca).

Answer (score 0):

You can now preview and edit markdown documents in Microsoft OneDrive for Business. It will automatically render as html files with the ".md" extension, and allow you to "open in text editor" and make changes directly within OneDrive.